# Pushing Response From Axios Call To Firebase - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, axios

I am doing an axios call to an api and am getting the desired response. However, I now need to take that response and push it up into my firebase firestore. I know how to push into the firestore, but I can't seem to access the data correctly from the axios call to push. Here is my code:

```
axios.get('https://somewhereontheweb.com/api/getgames', {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
          }
        })
          .then(response => {
            this.games = response.data;

            // push data into firestore?
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
```

I get a json array back from the api and can display it on my vue page (at this point it is an object) (so {{games}}). However, I am needing to take that data, iterate over it and in each iterations push the game data into firestore. Can you explain how to do that? I can write the code to push into firestore, but I can't write the code to iterate over the response from the axios call to push into firebase. I have been trying but am not getting anywhere. Any hint is great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a JSON string you are a getting then you can use something like this to iterate over it to manipulate it into the data structure you want:

```
for(var i in response.data){
  response.data[i].dosomething()
}
```

Also, might be a good idea to pass the iteration to a helper function with a promise that ends in sending it to Firestore.

Comment: Thank you! Upon review it turns out I am getting an object back (so array?). I put the code in that you have and did console.log(response.data[i]) instead. This gives me this response in the console:

CPM0to10: Getter & Setter
GPM0to10: Getter & Setter
__ob__: Object { value: {…}, dep: {…}, vmCount: 0 }
assists: Getter & Setter
championid: Getter & Setter
cs: Getter & Setter
etc.

So does this mean I am getting an object and if yes, what should I do?